# How to find corrent name for middle table in many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

This is not technical question, anyway it's related to good and clean code.

If I had tables `articles` and `tags`, I know the `taggings` can be good choice for middle table name.

What about other names? Like many-to-many in `articles` and `cateogories`. What's the best name for table between these two?

Is there any good approach? Or is it a question of English grammar? Please let me know.

Comment: How about `articles_tags`?

Comment: Primarily opinion-based question. There is no difference, if you ask me.

Comment: I recognise that this is a little OT for SO, but personally, I like articles_tags. I tend to alias linking tables with a two-letter abbreviation and all other tables with a one-letter abbreviation. So `... FROM tags t JOIN articles_tags ta ON ta.tag_id = t.tag_id JOIN articles a ON a.article_id = ta.article_id...`

Answer (score 1):

Best approach in my opinion would be to combine the two model names into one: `ArticleTag` (`TagArticle` makes less sense here). If you call it `Taggings`, then you (or someone maintaining your code / database) won't realise the relationship right away.

Same for `ArticleCategory` (`CategoryArticle` makes less sense).

Comment: Well, for what purpose `commet`s for the tables are ?

Comment: I can agree. I know this approach, actually rails guides suggests to use alphabetical order in tables inside that name.

Anyway rails generator is not friendly. `rails g model CategoryArticle category:references article:references` is preparing `category_articles` table, not `categories_articles` hah. Must be manually edited in migration and model class name.

Comment: @HAL9000 Database table comments (if you mean those) don't help you much in ActiveRecord models. Names, on the other hand, are pretty obvious. I think that the better and understandable the code, the less comments you need (be it database comments or code comments).

Comment: @StefanHuska Didn't know about the alphabetical order. Conventions are good. Even though I prefer to start many-to-many relationship names with the "most important" object (like Articles, in this case - because Categories and Tags are kind of "features" of Articles).